# Why was Josette under a sheet?

Tags: analysis, dark-shadows

In *Dark Shadows*, Josette is under a sheet during the scene in which Victoria sees her for the first time. Did it have any meaning other than being used as a suspense moment in which the viewer assumes that it is David at first?